# corona sdk trying to controlling character with keyboard input

Tags: lua, coronasdk

```
if (event.keyName == 'd' and event.phase == 'down'  ) then

Chr.xScale =  1
Chr.x = Chr.x + 5
Chr:setSequence("Run")
Chr:play()
return true
end
```

I am trying to move my "Chr" to the right but when I want to move him I have to press each time to move "Chr" how can I make it to hold d to move "Chr" to right

Answer (score 0):

Your listener will only run once with event.phase set to "down" once per keypress hence you will move your Chr object right by 5 pixels only once.

A solution to this would be to add a physics body to your object and then set a velocity by using `object:setLinearVelocity( xVelocity, yVelocity )` (https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/Body/setLinearVelocity.html)

This will then continuously move your object so to stop Chr from moving you must them call `object:setLinearVelocity( 0, 0)` when event.phase set to "up".